# how to get value from database in php by sending sms from device

Tags: php, android, sms

I am developing an android application in that when internet connection available i directly communicate with database using J SON parser and with use of web service but when no internet connectivity then i need to communicate with database by just sending text message is there any way for such communication??

Comment: I would recommend you reading about google cloud messaging http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: GCM work when internet connection available but in my case i want to communicate with mysql when internet connection not available and use of text msg to access database..

Comment: you mean you want to call a URL by just sending a text message , which will take care of db access

Comment: exactly i want to send text messages that will give result of according to query.. and sms that communicate with database

Comment: the only way you can do that, is buy a short code, send a text message to that short code, have kannel running on your server which will receive that message and call a URL accordingly to insert in your databse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an SMS API that provides virtual numbers. Generally speaking they turn an inbound SMS (sent to a virtual number you lease) into an `HTTP` request.

So from your mobile app, you'd do whatever is needed to compose / send the SMS payload, using your virtual number as the recipient.

Server side you just need to accept the callback form the API, and parse the incoming message for the payload, and (I assume) use the sender to identify the user behind it.

You should check out [Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/) (*disclaimer: I do some developer evangilism for them*), they're one of a few API's that provide virtual numbers for incoming SMS. Their pricing model would work out very well for your use case, as all inbound messages are free. You'll just pay a buck or so a month for the virtual number.

I've not added any documentation to this yet, but here's an example of something similar, the source just being [an Arduino with an GSM module](https://github.com/tjlytle/Pipeline). The Arduino relays environment data to a web service, using SMS as the data pipeline. Same basic process you'd use: Data -> SMS -> Virtual Number -> HTTP Callback -> Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to hit URL via text messages.

Comment: There is actually. See @Satya's response in the comments. Kannel (or any other SMS Gateway) would have to be installed on the recipient server, a shortcode would have to be configured to send messages to said server.